# how to build a panel carousel in bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, panel, carousel

Is there any way in Bootstrap 3 to make a row in which I can have a carousel of different panels, and by pannels I mean boxes with text, pictures and buttons, for example 9 panels showing 3 in each step of the carousel?

Comment: sorry but why dont you try, at least you should try

Comment: Please post the code you have tried.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the bootstrap fluid grid alone, just specify a .container-fluid container along with a .row-fluid row and give each one of your list items housing an image a .span* class, in this case 3 (3*4=12).

**HTML**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
              <div class="item active">
                    <ul class="thumbnails">
                        <li class="span3">
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h5>Caption</h5>
                            </div>
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                <img src="http://placehold.it/260x180" alt="">
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="span3">
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h5>Caption</h5>
                            </div>
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                <img src="http://placehold.it/260x180" alt="">
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="span3">
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h5>Caption</h5>
                            </div>
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                <img src="http://placehold.it/260x180" alt="">
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="span3">
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h5>Caption</h5>
                            </div>
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                <img src="http://placehold.it/260x180" alt="">
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="item">
                    <ul class="thumbnails">
                        <li class="span3">
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h5>Caption</h5>
                            </div>
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                <img src="http://placehold.it/260x180" alt="">
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="span3">
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h5>Caption</h5>
                            </div>
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                <img src="http://placehold.it/260x180" alt="">
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="span3">
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h5>Caption</h5>
                            </div>
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                <img src="http://placehold.it/260x180" alt="">
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="span3">
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h5>Caption</h5>
                            </div>
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                <img src="http://placehold.it/260x180" alt="">
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="item">
                    <ul class="thumbnails">
                        <li class="span3">
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h5>Caption</h5>
                            </div>
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                <img src="http://placehold.it/260x180" alt="">
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="span3">
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h5>Caption</h5>
                            </div>
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                <img src="http://placehold.it/260x180" alt="">
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="span3">
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h5>Caption</h5>
                            </div>
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                <img src="http://placehold.it/260x180" alt="">
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="span3">
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h5>Caption</h5>
                            </div>
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                <img src="http://placehold.it/260x180" alt="">
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
            <a data-slide="prev" href="#myCarousel" class="left carousel-control">‹</a>
            <a data-slide="next" href="#myCarousel" class="right carousel-control">›</a>
        </div>
</div>
</diV>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can try this, I never tried 3 but I checked the website

```
 <div class="item active">
  <img src="..." alt="...">
  <div class="carousel-caption">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

you can easily put all the items u wanna inside the `<div class="item active">`and then close it, and then open another div and so on ... make sure to try only with small pictures to get the idea ...
I used to do the same with the previous Bootstrap so i'm sure it will work :)